# awk, how to sort lines by number following matching word

Tags: sorting, awk

I have a text file like this:

```
word_1 23.66 word_5 0 word_7 123
word_5 6 word_1 2 word_7 12
word_7 23.7 word_2 21 word_1 3
...
```

Preferably using awk, how can I sort the lines by the number following "word_1"?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you some command sequence made of `sed` and `sort`:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)(word_1 )([^ ]+)(.*)/\3\t&/' your_file | sort -n | sed -r 's/[^\t]+\t(.*)/\1/'
```

1. the sed prepend the number after `word_1` and a tab before the line
2. the sort uses the prepended number for sorting
3. the second sed removes the prepended number and the tab, leaving the original line

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk supports sorting arrays based on index or value, see `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` in the manpage.

To achieve what you want, do something like this:

*sort.awk*

```
# Sort the indices numerically descending
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_desc" }

# Use the number following "word_1" as the index in the h hash
{ 
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    if($i == "word_1") 
      h[$(i+1),NR] = $0
}

END { for(k in h) print h[k] }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f sort.awk infile
```

Output:

```
word_1 23.66 word_5 0 word_7 123
word_7 23.7 word_2 21 word_1 3
word_5 6 word_1 2 word_7 12
```

Comment: this will overwrite records in case you have more than one record with the same value, one way to handling this is adding line number to the key, i.e `h[$(i+1),NR]=$0`

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about PROCINFO.